# Check if string value is present in identifier in JS or TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to check if string value is present in variable name (identifier)
For instance:

```
let stringVar = "hello";
let helloJohny = 45;
if (stringVar in helloJohny(name)) {
    return true;
}
```

where "helloJohny(name)" simply means the identifier but not the value stored for this identifier.

Or to set the identifier on the basis of a string value?
For instance:

```
let stringVar1 = "pretty";
let stringVar2 = "horse";
let (stringVar1 + stringVar2) = 45;
```

where: (stringVar1 + stringVar2) simply means the identifier built by the two string values, in this case - prettyhorse, so the result in system has to be understood as

```
let prettyhorse = 45;
```

???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: you need an object for using a property.

Comment: It would be illuminating to learn how so many people end up going down a path that leads to this question. Is it idiomatic in php or something like that?

Comment: You can do it using an object: `let stringVar = "pretty"; let obj = {};
obj[stringVar+"horse"] = 45`

Comment: @Sterex you don't need the last `let` :)

Comment: @Pointy it's been a long time since I wrote PHP but I don't remember it being idiomatic. However it did have the concept of [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593055/variable-variables-in-php-what-is-their-purpose), so it's possible to do that...albeit I've not seen anybody use them.

Comment: @vlaz and you can do it in UNIX/Linux shell programming, though over 30 years I can't recall doing it more than once or twice.

Comment: @Pointy Fixed. And yes, I was going to say the exact thing as `vlaz`! :)

Answer (score 2):

Objects in JavaScript allow for the accessing of properties using variables and expressions.

```js
let stringVar1 = "pretty";
let stringVar2 = "horse";

let content = {};
content[stringVar1 + stringVar2] = 45;

console.log(content.prettyhorse);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether variable is having string or not try this:

```
let stringVar = "hello";
let helloJohny = 45;

if (typeof stringVar === 'string') {
    alert('string present ')
}else {
    alert('string not present')
}
```

Comment: not the string type, but exact string value in the name of another variable (identifier)

Comment: No, to check if string value of one identifier is present in the identifier (not even in the value of another identifier, but in the identifier by itself). eval() can help - but it is strongly not recommended to use - what is the better choice?

Comment: @IgorTischenko the better choice is to use an object property and not a variable, because there's no way to dynamically form a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

if needs to check value and type both; try this one

```
let stringVar = "hello";
let helloJohny = 45;

if (typeof stringVar === 'string' && stringVar === 'hello') {
    alert('string present')
}else
  {
    alert('string not present')
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to know whether the string "hello" appears in the **name** of the variable `helloJohny`. In this case it does not, but if `stringVar` were "Jon" then the desired answer would be `true`.