# Defining PHP variables out of foreach?

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing this

```
foreach(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] as $x) {
    $x = $s->where('status', $x)->count() / $h * 100;
}
```

Now I'm trying to echo it like this:

```
echo $A; echo $B;
```

etc.

But it says `$A` is undefined, how do I do this?

Comment: There is no `$A` or `$B` maybe you mean `echo $x;`?

Comment: Perhaps [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593055/variable-variables-in-php-what-is-their-purpose) is what your after, so `$$x = ...`.  Although I would just stick with arrays instead).

Comment: You're overwriting `$x` with a calculated value, so you lose the original value like `'A'`. If you want both, use a second variable like `$count` instead of reassigning `$x`.

Comment: `$h` does not seems to have been defines either?

Comment: @NigelRen Yes it was the $$. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once this question lacks of explanation, I'm assuming that you want to assign a value for each letter of your array, as [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593055/variable-variables-in-php-what-is-their-purpose), as @nigel-ren has suggested:

```
foreach(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] as $x) {
    $$x = $s->where('status', $x)->count() / $h * 100;
}
```

For each iteration, `$$x` will create the variables `$A`, `$B`, `$C`, and `$D`, and assign the values returned by `$s->where('status', $x)->count() / $h * 100;`.

After that, you can echo the values of `$A`, `$B`, `$C`, and `$D`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reaching here, as it's not totally clear, but you are overwriting the value `$x` from the loop with the calculation.  You can get the status and the calculation like so:

```
foreach(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] as $status) {
    $x = $s->where('status', $status)->count() / $h * 100;
    echo "The result for $status is $x <br />";
}
```